# How to add a TextView to a GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I already know how to add String's to a gridView in android however I want to add textviews to format the text( Gravity, color, etc). This is my current code:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grades);
    ArrayList<TextView> display = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    ArrayAdapter<TextView> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, display);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    for(int i = 0; i<currentClass.grades.size(); i++)
    {
        TextView name = new TextView(this);
        TextView weight = new TextView(this);
        TextView cur_points = new TextView(this);
        TextView total_points = new TextView(this);
        TextView cur_percent = new TextView(this);

        name.setText(currentClass.grades.get(i).name);
        weight.setText(currentClass.grades.get(i).weight);
        cur_points.setText(currentClass.grades.get(i).cur_points);
        total_points.setText(currentClass.grades.get(i).total_points);
        cur_percent.setText(currentClass.grades.get(i).cur_percent);

        name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        weight.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        cur_points.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        total_points.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        cur_percent.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        name.setSingleLine(true);
        weight.setSingleLine(true);
        cur_points.setSingleLine(true);
        total_points.setSingleLine(true);
        cur_percent.setSingleLine(true);

        name.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        weight.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        cur_points.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        total_points.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        cur_percent.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        display.add(name);
        display.add(weight);
        display.add(cur_points);
        display.add(total_points);
        display.add(cur_percent);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Unfortunately when I run it the gridview simply gives me the information of each TextView: 
"android.id.widget.TextView({42f20a88 and so on}.

How would I add textview's to a gridView?

Comment: You'd probably be better off creating a custom adapter. I believe the reason your version is not working is ArrayAdapter and the arguments you're using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try it with something like this

gridview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

item.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:textSize="15px" >
</TextView>
```

Custom adapter class for textView

```
public class TextViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private final String[] textViewValues;

        public TextViewAdapter(Context context, String[] textViewValues) {
            this.context = context;
            this.textViewValues = textViewValues;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View gridView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                gridView = new View(context);

                // get layout from mobile.xml
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

                // set value into textview
                TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
                textView.setText(textViewValues[position]);  
            } else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }

            return gridView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return textViewValues.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

and then , finally set adapter in your main class

```
gridView.setAdapter(new TextViewAdapter(this, YOUR_ARRAY_WITH_TEXT_FOR_TEXTVIEWS));
```

also note that you can pass any other values like color of text and as another argument in constructor and then set them in adapter like ...

```
textView.setColor(textViewColors[position]);
```

for attributes that all textview have in common you can change the item.xml only :) 
i hope it helped you ....

Answer (score 0):

Simply do name.getText() and you're done!