# setTextSize in gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

How can I change the size of the text within my gridview?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  GridView gridView; 

  static final String[] numbers = new String[]{
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
        "F", "G", "H"}; 

  private GoogleApiClient client; 

  @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) v).setTextSize(30);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

I cannot change text size in xml because I have no TextView, only GridView. I can change text in the onclick method, but I cannot get it change the font size on load.

Comment: check this out, this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429829/how-to-add-a-textview-to-a-gridview-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To alter the appearance of the text in the `TextView`, you can simply use your own XML layout resource instead of the standard `android.R.simple_list_item_1`.  The source for the standard resource [can be found here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml).  You can start with something like that (even just copy the code in) as a layout resource in your project, and then modify it until you have the text looking the way you want.

Let's say your resource is called `R.layout.my_text_view_item`.  You can use it in your grid view by changing the line where you create the adapter to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.my_text_view_item, numbers);
```

With a class like an `ArrayAdapter`, this is generally the simplest way to modify the "look" of the individual elements.

For more advanced functionality, you can look into extending [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) or [`SimpleAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html).