# Accessing TextView inside twoway-gridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I want to use TextView inside two-way-gridview https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview .
I can successfully use ArrayAdapter with two-way-gridview. It work correctly as I want.
But when I adapt the example from [How to add a TextView to a GridView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429829/how-to-add-a-textview-to-a-gridview-in-android).
I got NullPointerException when accessing TextView. 

Here are my code.
**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final String[] numbers = new String[] {
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
            "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
            "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TwoWayGridView gridview = (TwoWayGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview = (TwoWayGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
//        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
//                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
        TextViewAdapter adapter = (TextViewAdapter) new TextViewAdapter(this, numbers);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

**layout.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.jaikra.sarit.wecare.TwoWayGridView.TwoWayGridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</com.jaikra.sarit.wecare.TwoWayGridView.TwoWayGridView>
```

**item.xml :**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:textSize="15px"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</TextView>
```

**TextViewAdapter.java :**

```
public class TextViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] textViewValues;

    public TextViewAdapter(Context context, String[] textViewValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.textViewValues = textViewValues;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return textViewValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);

            // set value into textview
            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            textView.setText(this.textViewValues[position]);

            textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }
}
```

**Problem :**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at com.jaikra.sarit.wecare.TextViewAdapter.getView(TextViewAdapter.java:54)
```

**Error :** 
Here is line 54 and 55.

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
            .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
    textView.setText(this.textViewValues[position]);
```

**Question :**
How to fix this problem?
What kind of programming topic should I need to read?

**After several attemp :**
I started to believe twoway-gridview has somethinkg behind the curtain that is not identical to ordinary gridView. I had opened the issue to the original developer, but any helps are welcome here.

Comment: I just add it. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the item of `GridView` you should `inflate`

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
TextView textView= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);
textView.setText(this.textViewValues[position]);
textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

            // set value into textview
            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            textView.setText(this.textViewValues[position]);

            textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }
```

Comment: Before : gridView = new View(context); After : (delete) gridView = new View(context); Error still remain. Thank for your attention.

Comment: Thank you for your help I have been reading on this for couple of days :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the gridView to a new instance, change to this:

gridView = convertView;

Then inflate it.

**EDITED**

In my adapter I use ViewHolders, this is what I would do:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);

        vi.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

    textView.setText(this.textViewValues[position]);

    textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

    return vi;

}
```

Don't forget to add this:

```
public static class ViewHolder{

    public TextView textView;

}
```

Comment: Before : gridView = new View(context); After gridView = convertView; I got the same error.

Comment: Before: public View getView(){...}. After : your answer with holder. infront of textView.setText() and textView.setTextColor() because it out of scope. The error is NullPointerException like the same, but change to line holder.textView.setText(this.textViewValues[position]);

Comment: Then I am suspecting an issue with your Context then, post your code where you pass through your context as you initialize the adapter.